# Howto get X and Y Postion of touch in a view in swift

Tags: swift, events, touch, screen

How can I get the X and Y Position of a touch on a UIView in Swift ? 
I have a UIViewController and a UIView.

Is this possible to get in a UIView or do I have to handle touches in a Controller.

I searched in Google and other sites, but I didn't find any good source on this. (I coudn't believe it)
I have no starting point, so I can't show any code.

Any hint where to find a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for UITouch, you have `locationInView` which return the location of the touch on a specific view. Example:

```
import UIKit

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch

        let point = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I do not understand. Where should I past your code ? I tried pasting this in my UIViewController and also in my UIView. But in both cases it doesn't recognize.

Comment: you have to import UIKit. You just paste it in your ViewController

Comment: I see the main problem. I obviously use a different swift version. It will be recognized with touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent). Thanks for helping.